# org-mode - is there a way I can make emacs treat a region to be of a given mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode - is there a way I can make emacs treat a region to be of a given mode (with syntax highlighting and so on). I tried the following for bash:

```
#+begin_src bash
# -*- mode:sh -*-
find . -type f -not -name '*[[:digit:]]*'
#+end_src
```

it doesn't work - it just shows the find line in grey. I want to be highlighted as if I were in a shell-script mode, or at least - black - with no org-mode parsing.

**Edit**:

The `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)` solves it, but org still interprets `[[:digit:]]` as a link:

```
#+begin_src sh 
find . -type f -not -name '*[[:digit:]]*'
#+end_src
```

can this be turned of somehow?

Comment: It's been a long time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246194/emacs-syntax-highlight-for-non-code-files/30263242#30263242

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)`

Comment: This solution requires me to have `(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '(
   (R . t)
   (sh . t)
   (python . t)
   (perl . t)
   ))` right?